# Comparing hash table to current table

Tags: perl

How can I accomplish a requirement like, if we have a file (a list of devices) which gets processed and saved in dataset?

The issue is how to remove the deleted devices from dataset.

For example, yesterday a list of 100 devices was saved in a dataset and today there are 90 devices to be processed.

In that case I think I should save the current dataset to a hash table and compare them with the new device list, removing further instances from the dataset.

It's bit confusing to me how to start with this.

I believe I need to

1. Create a hash table and save the current devices
2. Compare each device from the hash table and ignore it if it already exists

Here is the issue: how to compare the current list to the dataset? Either I create two hash tables, the current and the latest, and compare them and remove one from the dataset.

Comment: I am confused by your question, but applaud your use of *wherein*! Please make shorter sentences and I will be glad to help

Comment: Are you removing the old (not used) device data or just want to add new entries to the old list.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're comparing two hashes, as much as it does that you're comparing their keys.  In other words, you're comparing two arrays:  [`How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f)

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse ... Yes miller correct  Thanks a ton... :) got it gr8

Comment: Thanks Borodin and Brad for the response ...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you're comparing two hashes, as much as it does that you're comparing their keys. In other words, you're comparing two arrays: [How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f) –  Miller